# Python Numpy Value Error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (122,) (112,)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, syntax-error

I am trying find_peaks from scipy.signal to detect peaks and valleys in Python 3.7

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('a44171.xlsx',header=None)
df.columns = ['II','PLETH','ABP']
ppg = df["PLETH"]

series = np.array(ppg)
fs = 1/60
t = np.array([t*fs for t in range(len(series))])

peak_idx, _ = find_peaks(series, distance=60)
valley_idx, _ = find_peaks(-series, distance=60)

timedelay = peak_idx - valley_idx
```

I am getting the following error :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (122,) (112,)
```

There are some missing peaks I guess, so the dimensions are different.
Is there any code that I could add to fix the error?

Please help! I am new to Python programming.

Comment: Examine the data, and decide for yourself how you want to pair peak and valley indices.

Comment: @hpaulj - Thanks for reply. I have to delete some elements from the array so the dimensions are same. Is there any code that I could add to remove the error?